# Is there an error in many TQLI implementations in C?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

In the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48945001/eigenvalue-calculation-using-tqli-algorithm-fails-with-segmentation-fault) user Groo discovered, that in [this TQLI implementation](http://cacs.usc.edu/education/phys516/src/TB/eigen.c) for C done by the Collaboratory For Advanced Computing And Simulations of the University of Southern California there is the very basic mistake that all arrays are treated as if they would be one-based. Although it already seems very strange to me that a very renowned institution would have such a basic mistake in one of there codes it confuses me even more, that basically every other implementation of the TQLI algorithm and the related tred2 algorithm you can find online makes the same mistake.

Examples:

- [TU Graz](https://itp.tugraz.at/LV/sormann/AKNumPhysik/Finite_Elemente/c/eigensystem.c)
- [Stanford](http://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/cs/robotics/scohen/nr/tqli.c)

Is it really possible that all those different people made the same mistake or am I missing something? Was there a version of C were arrays were 1-based?

Comment: For your second question:  Could it be that the first element, 0-index, of the array is being used as the array size?  That's sometimes the convention.  I'm not aware of C ever having arrays that are 1-based though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question! Source code from above sources indicate that calculations are done on the arrays starting from index `1`.
Also

```
/*******************************************************************************
    Eigenvalue solvers, tred2 and tqli, from "Numerical Recipes in C" (Cambridge
    Univ. Press) by W.H. Press, S.A. Teukolsky, W.T. Vetterling, and B.P. Flannery
    *******************************************************************************/
```

used by https://www.onlinegdb.com employs `1`-based index arrays.  See:

```
/******************************************************************************/
void tqli(double d[], double e[], int n, double **z)
/*******************************************************************************
QL algorithm with implicit shifts, to determine the eigenvalues and eigenvectors
of a real, symmetric, tridiagonal matrix, or of a real, symmetric matrix
previously reduced by tred2 sec. 11.2. On input, d[1..n] contains the diagonal
elements of the tridiagonal matrix. On output, it returns the eigenvalues. The
vector e[1..n] inputs the subdiagonal elements of the tridiagonal matrix, with
e[1] arbitrary. On output e is destroyed. When finding only the eigenvalues,
several lines may be omitted, as noted in the comments. If the eigenvectors of
a tridiagonal matrix are desired, the matrix z[1..n][1..n] is input as the
identity matrix. If the eigenvectors of a matrix that has been reduced by tred2
are required, then z is input as the matrix output by tred2. In either case,
the kth column of z returns the normalized eigenvector corresponding to d[k].
*******************************************************************************/
{
    double pythag(double a, double b);
    int m,l,iter,i,k;
    double s,r,p,g,f,dd,c,b;

    for (i=2;i<=n;i++) e[i-1]=e[i]; /* Convenient to renumber the elements of e. */
...
}
```

You can find newer books were those algorithms are updated:

```
Numerical Recipes 3rd Edition: The Art of Scientific Computing
By William H. Press
```

[image]

uses `0`-index based arrays.

```
In respect to the TU Graz and Stanford algorithms
they just require supplying input data in the specific format.
```

This is the example from:
[Numerical Recipes 2nd ed. ANSI C Files](https://www.astro.umd.edu/~ricotti/NEWWEB/teaching/ASTR415/NR3/legacy/nr2/C_211/index.htm)

In this edition the `tqli` uses vectors and matrices which are 1-index based.
Calling the `tqli` requires special data preparation which are carries by 
 `vector` and `matrix` functions. The ordinary `float c[10][10]` is not directly used by `tqli` function. The data have to be prepared:

```
d=vector(1,NP);
e=vector(1,NP);
f=vector(1,NP);

a=matrix(1,NP,1,NP);

for (i=1;i<=NP;i++)
    for (j=1;j<=NP;j++) a[i][j]=c[i-1][j-1];
```

Zero based index matrix `c[10][10]` is used to fill 1-base index matrix `a`.

Full example is given [here](https://www.astro.umd.edu/~ricotti/NEWWEB/teaching/ASTR415/NR3/legacy/nr2/C_211/examples/xtqli.c).

```
#define NP 10
#define TINY 1.0e-6

int main(void)
{
    int i,j,k;
    float *d,*e,*f,**a;
    static float c[NP][NP]={
        5.0, 4.3, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0,-1.0,-2.0,-3.0,-4.0,
        4.3, 5.1, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0,-1.0,-2.0,-3.0,
        3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0,-1.0,-2.0,
        2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0,-1.0,
        1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0,
       -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0,
       -2.0,-1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0,
       -3.0,-2.0,-1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0,
       -4.0,-3.0,-2.0,-1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};

    d=vector(1,NP);
    e=vector(1,NP);
    f=vector(1,NP);
    a=matrix(1,NP,1,NP);
    for (i=1;i<=NP;i++)
        for (j=1;j<=NP;j++) a[i][j]=c[i-1][j-1];
    tred2(a,NP,d,e);
    tqli(d,e,NP,a);
    printf("\nEigenvectors for a real symmetric matrix\n");
    for (i=1;i<=NP;i++) {
        for (j=1;j<=NP;j++) {
            f[j]=0.0;
            for (k=1;k<=NP;k++)
                f[j] += (c[j-1][k-1]*a[k][i]);
        }
        printf("%s %3d %s %10.6f\n","eigenvalue",i," =",d[i]);
        printf("%11s %14s %9s\n","vector","mtrx*vect.","ratio");
        for (j=1;j<=NP;j++) {
            if (fabs(a[j][i]) < TINY)
                printf("%12.6f %12.6f %12s\n",
                    a[j][i],f[j],"div. by 0");
            else
                printf("%12.6f %12.6f %12.6f\n",
                    a[j][i],f[j],f[j]/a[j][i]);
        }
        printf("Press ENTER to continue...\n");
        (void) getchar();
    }
    free_matrix(a,1,NP,1,NP);
    free_vector(f,1,NP);
    free_vector(e,1,NP);
    free_vector(d,1,NP);
    return 0;
}
```

The conclusion is as follows:

> Is it really possible that all those different people made the same
>   mistake or am I missing something?

The algorithms are correct. The missing key in the puzzle was the proper data preparation.

> Was there a version of C were arrays were 1-based?

No.