# Algorithm example fails with conflicting types

Tags: c, algorithm

When I'm trying to use the TQLI algorithm provided by the Astronomy Department of the University of Maryland from [here](https://www.astro.umd.edu/~ricotti/NEWWEB/teaching/ASTR415/NR3/legacy/nr2/C_211/index.htm) I get an error for conflicting types. I put the example on repl.it [here](https://repl.it/@AxelFiedler1/UMDTQLIExample). Why is the execution failing and what can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Why are you indexing arrays from `1`?

Comment: @WeatherVane Good question! I asked the same one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48949875/is-there-an-error-in-many-tqli-implementations-in-c/48957728#48957728). Apparently this is done on purpose.

Comment: NR has always done strange things with indexes, here it's due to indexing, e.g. `c[i-1][j-1];`

Comment: @AlexReynolds Interesting. I did the change and now I get a lot of errors about multiple definition of things like nrerror. Where does this come from?

Comment: Ok I resolved this. Now I get an error that I have undefined references to for example vector and matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into problems in the compile process because the Numerical Recipes are built from a number of smaller files. Here you have found the conflicting `fmin` issue (you can rename that function `fmin2` (or whatever) to avoid the conflict in `nr.h`). You then need the following files to compile the example:

```
nr.h       /* header files */
nrutil.h
```

and

```
nrutil.c   /* source files */
tqli.c
tred2.c
pythag.c
(yourfile.c)
```

Then it is simply a matter of compiling the sources. You can use a `Makefile` or just a single compiler string, e.g. (for `gcc`)

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -finline-functions -std=gnu11 -Ofast \
-Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-parameter nrutil.c tqli.c tred2.c pythag.c \ 
-o yourexename yourfile.c
```

It should then compile without error or warning and you should be able to run it, e.g.

```
$ ./yourexename

Eigenvectors for a real symmetric matrix
eigenvalue   1  =   0.591722
     vector     mtrx*vect.     ratio
   -0.177382    -0.104961     0.591722
    0.154260     0.091279     0.591721
    0.170442     0.100854     0.591720
   -0.453325    -0.268244     0.591724
    0.455130     0.269310     0.591721
   -0.174737    -0.103397     0.591727
   -0.214000    -0.126629     0.591724
    0.470052     0.278139     0.591720
   -0.434657    -0.257197     0.591724
    0.129761     0.076782     0.591718
Press ENTER to continue...
...
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That was really insightful.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Those multi-pieces compiles can be frustrating at first, but once you figure out that you need each file that provides one of the functions you are using, it's not to bad after that. Then you just have to hunt for the file whatever function you are missing is defined in and add it to your list of files to be compiled.